# how do i exclude a source tree from a gradle javadoc task

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I'm sure this is trivial, but can't find any examples out there to remove a source tree from the generated java doc.  My source tree is

```
src/main/java/...
src/test/java/...
src/samples/java/...
```

I have tried two tasks, neither seem to work.

```
javadoc {
    exclude               "src/test/**"
    exclude               "src/samples/**"
}

task gendocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath += configurations.compile
    exclude               "src/test/java/**/*"
}
```

Here's the complete file (updated to try Lance Java's suggestion), but no joy.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.ibm.watson.iot.sound'
version = '0.0.1'

description = 'IoT Sound project build configurations'

sourceSets.all { set ->
    def jarTask = task("${set.name}Jar", type: Jar) {
        baseName = baseName + "-$set.name"
        from set.output
    }
    artifacts { archives jarTask }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src/main/java"
            srcDir "src/client/java"
            srcDir "src/test/java"  
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/java"
            srcDir "src/client/java"
            srcDir "src/test/java"  
        }
    }

    client {
        java {
            srcDir "src/client/java"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/client/java"
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath    
        compileClientJava {
            sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
            targetCompatibility = "1.7"
        }
    }
}


// Make so javadoc errors do not cause the gradle command to fail
if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    allprojects {
      tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
      }
    }
}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava.matching {
        exclude 'src/test/**'
        exclude 'src/samples/**'
    }
}

test { 
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "STARTED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
    exclude 'com/ibm/watson/iot/sound/*/**/*'
    include 'com/ibm/watson/iot/sound/*TestSuite*'
}

task release(type: Zip, dependsOn : [javadoc,mainJar, clientJar, publishToMavenLocal]) {
    description = 'Builds the release zip for this project'
            into ('caa') {
                from ('resources') {
                    include '*.properties'
                }
            }
            into('caa/lib')  {
                // from ('build/libs/IoT-Sound-0.0.1.jar')  
                from clientJar.outputs.files    
                from (configurations.compile)  
                from jar.outputs.files          
                from ('src/client/java/logback.xml')
                from ('caa.properties')
                from ('wpml.properties')
            }
            into('caa/bin') {
                from ('scripts') 
                fileMode 0755
            }
            into('caa/samples') {
                from ('src/samples/java') 
            }
            into ('caa/docs') {
                from ('build/docs') 
            }
}

println release.archiveName
println relativePath(release.destinationDir)
println relativePath(release.archivePath)

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
        api(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'IoT-Sound-Client' 
            artifact clientJar 
       }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'javacpp-presets' 
    all*.exclude group: 'com.github.fommil.netlib', module: 'all'
}

repositories {

     maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/" }
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version:'3.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version:'1.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'    // need by SII
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math', version:'2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version:'3.4.1'
    compile group: 'gov.sandia.foundry', name: 'cognitive-foundry', version:'3.4.3'
    compile group: 'tw.edu.ntu.csie', name: 'libsvm', version: '3.17' 
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'   
    compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version:'0.5.0'  
    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version:'0.5.0' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things wrong with your script so will address them in a separate answer

1. `src/test/x` should NOT be under `sourceSets.main` (it's already under `sourceSets.test`). Putting test sources in the main sourceSet will mean that test classes end up being packed inside your jar!!
2. `java` folders should NOT be under `sourceSets.x.resources`. Java folders should contain `*.java` files only. Any resources (eg `*.xml` and `*.properties`) should live in `src/x/resources` folders. Putting `java` folders in your resources will mean your plain `*.java` files will also end up in the jar!!
3. If you only want specific folders to be included by `javadoc` then don't start with `sourceSets.main.allJava`. Just add the specific folders you need as suggested by @Stanislav
4. The `exclude` inside `FileTree.matching { }` is relative to the `FileTree` root. `exclude 'src/test/**'` and `exclude 'src/samples/**'` aren't valid at this point. Same goes for `exclude` inside `javadoc`. Take a look at the `exclude` under your `test` task. These are correctly root relative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all my shortcomings, but you have not answered the question.

Comment: Yes I did "If you only want specific folders to be included by javadoc then don't start with sourceSets.main.allJava. Just add the specific folders you need as suggested by @Stanislav"

Comment: I don't want to specify the folders I need.  I want to specify the folders I don't need.

Comment: A `FileTree` is an abstract concept represented by an interface. In this instance, multiple root folders are used to build a single `FileTree` collection. Once the `FileTree` is created, the root folders are lost/hidden by the abstraction. You can't use them in exclusions and you can't "see" them via the `FileTree` interface. Exclusions can only be done relative to the `FileTree` root (which is the merged set of files & subfolders under the root folders).